# Building JSON with java overwrites values

Tags: java, json, web-services, nested-loops

I'm trying to represent some info from the database with a json, the json structure is created well but don't know why overwrittes the last record from the database. So on my json I just got the last value readed instead al the values.

To do this I use a ResultSet from the main values and an iteration. Inside this iteration I get the related information, so this data is nested on the json. that's my code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
          ResultSet sections = null;
          ResultSet questions = null;
          JSONObject section = new JSONObject();
          JSONObject question = new JSONObject();
          Db d = new Db();


          d.makeJDBCConnection();
          sections = d.getSections();
          while(sections.next()){
              section.put("name", sections.getString("sectionName"));
              section.put("id", sections.getInt("id"));
              questions = d.getQuestions(sections.getInt("id"));
              while(questions.next()){
                  // id, statement
                  question.put("id", questions.getInt("id"));
                  question.put("statement", questions.getString("statement"));
                  section.put("questions", question);
              }
          }

          json.append("section", section);

          return Response.status(200).entity(json.toString()).build();
```

I checked the debug and I get all the records but on the json response I just get the last one result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Initialize your `section` and `question` inside loop

2.) Add `section` into `json` inside `outter` while loop

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
          ResultSet sections = null;
          ResultSet questions = null;
          JSONObject section = null;
          JSONObject question = null;
          Db d = new Db();


          d.makeJDBCConnection();
          sections = d.getSections();
          while(sections.next()){

              section = new JSONObject();
              // initialize new one inside every iteration

              section.put("name", sections.getString("sectionName"));
              section.put("id", sections.getInt("id"));
              questions = d.getQuestions(sections.getInt("id"));
              while(questions.next()){
                  // id, statement

                  question = new JSONObject();
                  // initialize new one inside every iteration

              question.put("id", questions.getInt("id"));
                  question.put("statement", questions.getString("statement"));
                  section.put("questions", question);
              }
          json.append("section", section);
          // ^^ add every created record 
          // should be inside the loop
          }
```

Comment: I tried your code and runs perfect! you solved my problem

Comment: @proktovief thanks for the compliment , i am glad i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You're repeatedly updating the same "question" and "section" object. You should create a new "section" object each time through the "while(sections.next())" loop and same thing for "question."

Comment: this will again show only one record because this ` json.append("section", section);` should be inside the loop

Comment: Yes, but if he moves "JSONObject section = new JSONObject()" to within the while loop, he will immediately realize that he has to move the append in there too.